# Python tkinter treeview return iid from selected item

Tags: python, tkinter, tree, treeview

In Python tkinter treeview I am trying to make a display that will show certain things based on the iid of the selected treeview item, it takes place on a selection event (mouse click) but I cannot get this working:

```
def tree_click_event (event):
    iid = treedisplay.identify(event.x,event.y)

treedisplay = ttk.Treeview(root,selectmode='browse')
treedisplay.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', tree_click_event)
treedisplay.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
```

error:

```
TypeError: tree_click_event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

this is condensed down to just creating the tree, packing it in a tkinter window, looking for people familiar with this module to know exactly what I've done wrong

Thank you for your example @BryanOakley, it works to get the text of the item. Is there no way to get the below code working though?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview()
        self.tree.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.tree_click_event)

        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text="Item %s" % i)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def tree_click_event(self, event):
        iid = self.tree.identify(event.x,event.y)
        print (iid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[identify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.identify) requires three arguments and you are only passing it two. The first argument represents a component that you want to identify, and needs to be one of the following: region, item, column, row, or element.

For example:

```
iid = treedisplay.identify("item", event.x,event.y)
```

Note: while the above is syntactically correct, it won't quite do what you think it does. In the case of the `<<TreeviewSelect>>` event, you won't get an x and y coordinate. That is because the event can be fired by both keyboard and mouse events. The `identify` method should be used for explicit bindings to mouse events, and is mostly only used for low level bindings.

If you want the selected item, use the `selection` method which will return a list of item ids:

```
for item in treedisplay.selection():
    item_text = self.tree.item(item,"text")
```

Comment: I received an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673883/python-tkinter-treeview-get-return-iid-of-selected-item/43676612?