# Python tkinter treeview get / return iid of selected item

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

It's meant to get the `iid` of the treeview item when a user clicks on an item and print it out but for some reason `identify()` is not receiving the the event.y variable, perhaps?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview()
        self.tree.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.tree_click_event)

        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text="Item %s" % i)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def tree_click_event(self, event):
        iid = self.tree.identify(event.x,event.y)
        print (iid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Upon clicking an item in the treeview the error is:

```
TypeError: identify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

In response to @TessellatingHeckler 's comment, an edit made to the code based on the link does not produce an error but still will not print out the `iid`:

```
def tree_click_event(self, event):
    item = self.tree.identify('item', event.x,event.y)
    print (item)
```

Thank you for the accepted answer from @CommonSense in summary it seems I needed to use self.tree.bind('<1>', self.tree_click_event) instead of treeviewselect for this particular problem, but thanks for providing a second way of doing things aswell

Comment: So what happens exactly? Are you getting an error? Nothing printed? Wrong thing printed?

Comment: title should summarize question

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I have edited my post to reflect your comment

Comment: Another solution is `iid=tree.focus()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/pod/event.pod) `x, y` coordinates are

> Valid for KeyPress, KeyRelease, ButtonPress, ButtonRelease, Motion, Enter, Leave, Expose, Configure, Gravity, and Reparent events.

So here's a little *workaround* for your problem with some debug prints (notice `<<TreeviewSelect>>` event coordinates!):

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview()
        self.tree.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', self.tree_click_event)
        self.tree.bind('<1>', self.on_click)
        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text="Item %s" % i)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def tree_click_event(self, event):
        real_coords = (self.tree.winfo_pointerx() - self.tree.winfo_rootx(),
                       self.tree.winfo_pointery() - self.tree.winfo_rooty())
        item = self.tree.identify('item', *real_coords)
        print('********** tree selection event **********')
        print('looks like this virtual event doesnt support event coordinates')
        print('event.x: %d, event.y: %d' % (event.x, event.y))
        print('real.x: %d, real.y: %d' % real_coords)
        print('clicked on', self.tree.item(item)['text'])
        print('******************************************\n')


    def on_click(self, event):
        item = self.tree.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
        print('********** tree mouse click event **********')
        print('clicked on', self.tree.item(item)['text'])
        print('event.x: %d, event.y: %d' % (event.x, event.y))
        print('******************************************\n')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

*Output:*
[image: output]

Comment: thank you sooo much! and you've provided both functions so I can choose... brilliant

Comment: @new_to_coding, it's not quite true, because user can select items via navigation keys, hence mouse_click event there just for comparsion purposes. Anyway, if the selection event is triggered by the navigation key (or anything except mouse) this code will fail either, but I would stay with this option if you ask me (there're more things to code)! So point of my answer - you can't rely on coordinates only, but if you really need them under selection event - there's a workaround, that I showed!

Comment: any idea how I might approach getting the parent text of a selection using <<TreeviewSelect>> I can submit as a separate question and link it here if you want

Comment: @new_to_coding, it's really broad question from you, since you doesnt mention a desired behavior. Simpliest option there (if user can select only one item at the time `selectmode='browse'`) would be an one-line `print(self.tree.item(self.tree.selection()[0])['text'])` under `tree_click_event`.

Comment: man I'm sorry, I appreciate the help, I'm just rushing my questions so not thinking them through properly, I'll try that now, thank you

Comment: I have created a new question with the specifics of my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681006/python-tkinter-treeview-get-return-parent-name-of-selected-item

Comment: @new_to_coding, also I think, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30615520/6634373) is useful for you too. [Focus](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.focus) returns current item in focus (last selected if `selecmode != 'browse'`)