# Python tkinter treeview get / return parent name of selected item

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to return the parent of a tkinter treeview selection upon a selection event, so if the selection changes to "child" I would like it to print "parent", working example below, currently it prints the selection, not the parent of the selection:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', self.tree_select_event)
        self.parent_iid = self.tree.insert("", "end", text="Parent")
        self.child_iid = self.tree.insert(self.parent_iid, "end", text="Child")

        self.root.mainloop()

    def tree_select_event(self, event):
        print (self.tree.item(self.tree.selection()[0])['text'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Currently prints upon selection of Child:

```
"Child"
```

Desired output upon selection of child:

```
"Parent"
```

Comment: Have you read any documentation? The method for obtaining the parent of an item is documented.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes but it requires the iid of the selected item .parent(iid) and I am trying to cover both mouse click selection and arrow key selection of items in treeview and I can't see how I get the iid of an item from an arrow key release event from the documentation. So I am using .bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>') to cover both and I can only return the text of a selected item using this event so it's difficult, having multiple IDs (with the same name but different iid) with different parents to get the parent of an ID

Comment: I don't understand your response. You have code that can return an id. There is a method that takes an id and returns a parent. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I am realizing that .selection() returns an iid also, I read elsewhere it just returns text values from the treeview, sorry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
def tree_select_event(self, event):
    item_iid = self.tree.selection()[0]
    parent_iid = self.tree.parent(item_iid)

    if parent_iid:
        print(self.tree.item(parent_iid)['text'])
    else:
        print(self.tree.item(item_iid)['text'])
```

..and it's well documented [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.parent).